# Performance of generated T-SQL from Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

I recently used Entity Framework for a project, despite my DBA's strong disapproval. So one day he came to my office complaining about generated T-SQL that reaches his database.

For instance, when I want to select a product based on the id, I write something like this:

```
context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id==id);
```

Which translates to

```
SELECT ... FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID=@id)
```

So he is shouting, "Why on earth would you write a SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1)"

So I changed my code to

```
context.Products.Where(p=>p.Id==id).ToList().FirstOrDefault()
```

and this produces a much cleaner T-SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID=@id
```

The inner query and the TOP 1 dissappeared. Enough mambling, my question is this: Does the first query really put an overhead for SQL Server? Is it harder to parse than the second method? The Id column has a Clustered index on. I want a good answer so I can rub it on his face (or mine)

Thanks,
Themos

Comment: Can you ask him to send you the execution plans for both queries? That would show you the over head. However I think as a DBA it is important to identify bottlenecks in TSQL queries and then help the developers understand how to code more efficient. Rubbing each others faces in it is a ego battle which is not going to really benefit anyone. Using a ORM tool can sometimes lead to bad SQL being generated. However writing TSQL code badly has the same effect. Sounds like the DBA is very much set in his ways and you will be fighting a personal opinion which is very hard to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the queries manually and comparing the executions plans?

The biggest problem here isn't that the SQL isn't perfectly formed to your DBA's standards (although I'm fairly certain that the query engine will optimize out the extra select). The second query actually returns the entire contents of the Products table which you then analyse in memory and this is definitely a task that should be performed by the DB and not the application layer.

In short, he's being a pedant; leave it the way it was.

Comment: The filtering still works in the database, see the resulting (posted) SQL.

Comment: @HansKesting The filter on ID is translated into SQL. The `FirstOrDefault()` is translated into SQL in the original query, but not in the revised query, working on the materialized resultset instead. It still returns the same result, but processed in memory instead of by the database.